# Required fields in swagger model description

Tags: c#, swagger

What is the right way to make some fields required in data model? For now, I have all fields marked optional. The only option I have found is to use `[Required]` attribute, like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class SomeModel {
    [Required]
    public DateTime lastModified { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yep that's the correct DataAnnotation to use

Comment: There is no "right way". There are ways that work in your circumstance and those that don't. You've found a way that works. Use it.